# Scrape multiple page using post method

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    
    url = "https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_3.php"

    payload='serial=19&office_serial=&submit2=Details'
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'CAKEPHP=u6u40lefkqnm45j49a5i0h6bs3',
    'Origin': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
         yield SeleniumRequest(
            url=self.url,
            method='POST',
            body=self.payload,
            wait_time=3,
            screenshot=True,
            headers=self.headers,
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True,
        )

    def parse(self,response):
          title=response.xpath("//td[@class='kiso']//text()").getall()
          print(title)
```

I am scraping the data from the page using the post method but every data has different `serial number`  these is page link https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php

[image]

Then using the post method to get request from these page but every data has `different serial number` go to payload and every page has different serial number than how I scrape multiple page because every data has different serial number
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as a result?

Comment: basically I scrape `name`,`Firm name` and other detail also But the main problem is that every data has differnet `serinal number` i am trying to solve that problem how I get data when  every page has different  `serinal number` go to payload and every page has different serial number

Comment: You are overcomplicating this - the serials are given in the main page-link, so you'll probably have to scrape the .php for the serials and iterate the page end amount until it reaches the last page in the payload. Then use these serial to scrape the info from the page that you need. It may take some time to get it right but seems pretty standard.

Comment: where is the `serial` in main page can share me I am not find it

Comment: So are you saying that every data has a different serial number?

Comment: Yes I am saying these

Comment: @AmenAziz You can display all results and use CTRL+F on after inspect element on the elements page, you should see serial numbers. As working dollar mentioned, its also in the .php. You should be able to extract these per page.